# ColdFusion 11 on Windows 10 with IIS is not working

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-10, coldfusion-11

I installed CF 11 on Windows 10 Professional using IIS option as shown below. But when I go to IIS I don't see `CFIDE` folder there:

[image]

I thought the CF installation process would have created a `CFIDE` folder in IIS with its subfolder `Administrator` that points to the Administrator URL. But IIS did have any such folder. If I remember in Windows 7, installing CF 11 with IIS option automatically configure Administrator website in IIS - at least that what I recall I had done in Win7.
So I manually added a virtual directory in IIS and named it `CFIDE` with physical path as `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE` that is a correct path on my system. But when I go to `http://localhost/CFIDE/administrator/` or go to `All Programs-->Adobe-->Administrator` in Windows, I get the following error. Please help:

[image]

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for https://serverfault.com as it is not a programming or language question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CF11 was initially not supported for windows 10. One of the recent update of CF11 started supporting Windows 10. You would need to install ColdFusion and Select Built in Web server while installing ColdFusion. Once its installed, apply the latest update from CF admin and re-configure the IIS connector using Web server Configuration tool. 
OR
Apply the latest update manually: 
http://coldfusionx.blogspot.in/2017/07/how-to-install-coldfusion-updates.html 
And re-configure the IIS connector.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I first downloaded the latest UPDATE 12 for CF 11 from [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-11-updates.html) and then followed the link you provided on how to run the downloaded update. I then configured the IIS connector by using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmNfVAo4aB0)

Comment: Might be one bug resulting from this solution: Enablign/disable robust exception informations does not reflect on IIS where the graphic CF simplified error message appears no matter what.