# How to configure website in IIS for ColdFusion

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, coldfusion-11, coldspring

I am new to ColdFusion development. I am working on a project in which we are using ColdFusion 11 and ColdSpring. I have to configure the website in IIS as currently I am not able to serve it in a browser.

Can anyone please guide me how to configure and view the website.

Comment: You configure IIS using the Web Server Configuration Tool in GUI or command-line mode. Just follow the docs - [Configure your system](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/configuring-your-system.html) About half-way down that page is the section **Configuring IIS in Windows**. If you are installing on Windows 10 see this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45437852/1636917